# Checking if a String is a number using switch

Tags: java, string, numbers, switch-statement

I have to make a program which tells if a `String` **that I type in my keyboard** is a number, by using a `switch`. I know how to do it with try and catch, but I don't know how to do it with `switch`.

Any tips?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Java, already edited.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as 'too broad', it's really not!

Comment: @Coulton OP shows no effort whatsoever solving it himself, requiring us to do it all for him and also asking us to explain it --> too broad. That is my opinion. If the community disagrees, the question will not be closed.

Comment: The issue is very much isolated, to determine if a string value is a number using a switch, how much more isolated can you get?  The only issue I can see if that the OP shows no sign of effort on their part, [but they might have already researched the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/894792).

Comment: As I said, I've tried with try and catch, I've tried also converting my String to int with Integer.parseInt(myString), but I don't really know how to use a switch there. Also we haven't seen yet public static boolean... Only public static void main, so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to check each characer in the `String`. Something like this would probably work.

```
static boolean isNumber(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        // Debatable.
        return false;
    }
    int decimalCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        switch (s.charAt(i)) {
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                // These are all allowed.
                break;
            case '.':
                if (i == 0 || decimalCount > 0) {
                    // Only allow one decimal in the number and not at the start.
                    return false;
                }
                decimalCount += 1;
                break;
            default:
                // Everything else not allowed.
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem here is that we haven't seen "static boolean isNumber" yet, I've tried it and it works but I cannot use it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think that the code can be run within the `static boolean isNumber` and the final `}`

Answer (score 2):

Up to Java7 you can use `switch(String)` statement.

---

But here you have enough with `switch(int)` and a little workaround:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String a = "2";

    switch (Integer.parseInt(a)) {
    default: 
        System.out.print("is a number");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works but I need to type the String myself (Scanner). If I type a number, it works, but if I type a letter, for example, it fails. I need to show a message if it isn't a number, too. Is there any way that I can do that? (For example: case (it's not a number): Syso ("It's not a number").)

Comment: This is not using `Switch(String)` and will throw an exception if the string is not a valid number. See [Integer.ParseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) *Throws:
    NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.*

Comment: This will be achieved using `try{}catch`, so if you cannot use it, just check @OldCurmudgeon answer, and note, `static boolean isNumber(String s)` is a new function created by him/her, not a java built-in, that you cannot use, simply move all the code inside `static boolean isNumber` to your main code if necessary

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I got asking to some classmates and thinking it quietly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 


    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
    String myNumber;
    int tf;
    myNumber = entry.next();

    try {
        Double.parseDouble(myNumber);
        tf = 1;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        tf = 0;
    }


    switch(tf) {

    case 1:
        System.out.println("Is a number");
    break;

    default:
        System.out.println("No es un número");
        break;

    }




}
```

Thanks to the community for being so nice!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a shorter code BUT it uses regular expressions, which if Halo is just starting with Java, he may have not seen that topic yet. But then it answers the question too so here it is:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String expression = scanner.nextLine();
String matches = new Boolean(expression.matches("\\d+")).toString();
switch (matches) {
case "true":
    System.out.println("IT'S a number");
    break;
case "false":
    System.out.println("NOT a number");
}
scanner.close();
```